# Error copying the structure to another of same type

Tags: c++

Below is a c++ snippet,

```
struct node {
    struct shm_ipc_msg_s msg;
    struct node *next;
};

enqueue_shm_events(Queue *q, shm_ipc_msg *msg)
{
    struct node *temp = new node;
    temp->msg = msg;      // error here!!!!
    if (q->front == NULL)
       q->front = temp;
    else
       q->rear->next = temp;
}
```

Error :

```
error: no match for 'operator=' in 'temp->node::msg = msg'
```

Can anyone help me rectify this error

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are assigning a `struct shm_ipc_msg *` to a `struct shm_ipc_msg_s` (it's not a pointer in the `node` struct and the struct names are different too).

Comment: Perhaps you want `temp->msg = *msg;`

Comment: @AndyDalton It's impossible to know without knowing the relationships between the two struct types. They may be completely different and incompatible struct types for all we know. IMO, the question should possibly be migrated to SO, but it lacks important information about these unknown types.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

1. Your type names are different
2. You are assigning a pointer to a non-pointer

Fix 1:  Various fixes. One possibility is `typedef struct shm_ipc_msg_s shm_ipc_msg`

Fix 2: Change your failing line to `temp->msg = *msg;` to dereference the pointer so you can copy the actual struct contents